# How to return back the full model object after create

Tags: php, laravel

I have `posts` table containing `id , name, status, desc`, status is `enum('complete','incomplete')` when I create a new post like this:

```
CreatePostRequest contains:
'name' , 'desc'

// create method
public function __invoke(CreatePostRequest $request)
{ 
   $post = Post::create($request->validated());
   dd($post);
}
output:
  #attributes: array:10 [
    "name" => "test"
    "desc" => "desc"
  ]
```

How can make `status` return with object after created!

I know the way of `megre_array`, but I do not thing this is a good idea  espleacly when I have a lot of columns in table!

So is there any other way to return full of elequent object!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `refresh` on that Model instance to reload it with fresh attributes from the database:

```
return $post->refresh();
```

`refresh` will refresh the attributes of the current instance and return the current instance.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Retrieving Models - Refreshing Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#refreshing-models) `refresh`

Comment: WOW, that is awesome! `$post->refresh()` Thank you